# emacs open includes in code files, multiple directories

Tags: c, emacs, header-files, libraries, include-path

ECB, cscope, xcscope. All working. Is cedet necessary?

MSVS, eclipse, code::blocks, xcode. All of them allow easy click on an included source file and take you to it.
Now, with the above setup, emacs does too.
Except emacs doesn't take you to the std:: libraries, doesn't assume their location in /src/linux or some such. Emacs is a little blind and needs you to manually set it up.

But I can't find anything that explains how to set up ff-find-other-file to search for any other directories, let alone standard major libraries, outside of a project's directory.

So, how do I do it?

Edit; Most important is to be able to request on either a file name (.h, .c, .cpp, .anything) or a  library (iostream) and open the file in which the code resides.

Answer (score 0):

Additional directories for `ff-find-other-file` to look into are in `ff-search-directories` variable which by default uses the value of `cc-search-directories`, so you should be able to customize any of the two to specify additional search paths.

As for the second question about requesting a file name and finding corresponding file, something like that will do:

```lisp
(defun ff-query-find-file (file-name)
  (interactive "sFilename: ")

  ;; dirs expansion is borrowed from `ff-find-the-other-file` function    
  (setq dirs
        (if (symbolp ff-search-directories)
            (ff-list-replace-env-vars (symbol-value ff-search-directories))
          (ff-list-replace-env-vars ff-search-directories)))

  (ff-get-file dirs file-name))
```

Call it with <kbd>M-x ff-query-find-file</kbd> or bind it to a key to your liking.